# Grouping documents by an array, treat array as a set

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a fairly simple-sounding task I'd like to achieve using MongoDB's aggregation pipeline. I want to treat the arrays in one field as sets (i.e., disregarding order and duplicate), and group by them. As an example, the collection might be:

```js
[
    {
        _id: 1
        names: ["a", "b"]
    },
    {
        _id: 2
        names: ["c", "a"]
    },
    {
        _id: 3
        names: ["b", "a"]
    }
]
```

And the result I want back is something like:

```js
[
    {
        names: ["a", "b"],
        count: 2
    },
    {
        names: ["a", "c"],
        count: 1
    }
]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) the results to make them consistent for a grouping key. There really is no other way:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$names" },
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1, "names": 1} },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "names": { "$push": "$names" }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$names",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

Returns just like you ask:

```js
[
    {
        "_id": ["a", "b"],
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "_id": ["a", "c"],
        "count": 1
    }
]
```

Whilst there are quite a few operators that work on array like "sets", none of them "reorder" the array content into a consistent way that would apply when grouping. This is only ever done when you `$sort`.

Even if arrays contained "duplicates", and had some set transformation applied they are still not consistently ordered:

```js
db.testa.insert_many([
    { "a" : [ "a", "b" ] },
    { "a" : [ "b", "a" ] },
    { "a" : [ "b", "a", "a" ] }
])

db.testa.aggregate({ "$project": { "_id": 0, "a": { "$setUnion": [ "$a", [] ] } } })
```

That sample returns of course:

```js
{ "a" : [ "b", "a" ] }
{ "a" : [ "a", "b" ] }
{ "a" : [ "a", "b" ] }
```

So you would "still" need to `$unwind` and `$sort` in order to get a consistent "set" for grouping purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely get your result by stitching together multiple aggregation pipelines.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
 {$unwind:"$names"},
 {$sort:{_id:1, names:1}},
 {$group:{_id:"$_id", names:{$push:"$names"}}},
 {$group:{_id:"$names", count:{$sum:1}}},
 {$project:{_id:0, names:"$_id", count:1}}
])
```

It emits:

```
{ 
    "count" : NumberInt(1), 
    "names" : [
        "a", 
        "c"
    ]
}
{ 
    "count" : NumberInt(2), 
    "names" : [
        "a", 
        "b"
    ]
}
```